# react-native-video can't display HLS stream on Android

Tags: android, react-native, http-live-streaming

I'm using Android device to push a video stream with RTMP to SRS. In SRS I use HLS to deliver the stream.Then I use react-native-video to fetch the stream,but it is in white,it can't display the stream.

SRS logs show react-native-video had fetched the stream.The react-native-video onError logs

> { error: { extra: -22, what: 1 } }

However, when I put a video in SRS in advance,react-native-video can display the stream well.

I'm sure the pushed stream encoded in the right video/audio codec.

Comment: I have the same problem.. with react native and EXPO

Comment: for Expo try source "overrideFileExtensionAndroid" parameter if your URL doesn't have it on the end.